# Why can't my browser see my hosted php files?

Tags: php

I'm sure I'm doing something dumb, but I can't tell what it is.

On my remote host, I have a subdir with a bunch of files.
When I request this directory, I can see a listing of the files within this dir.

However, if request any file suffixed .php, my browser says that the resource is not available. Firefox tells me that it can't find the file I requested.

I guess that this is a permissions issue.
For testing purposes, I have set the permissions as permissively as possible.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

Resource not available (HTTP 503) depends a lot on your server configuration. If you are using a FastCGI version of PHP, have you started the FastCGI backend? If you are using Apache and mod_php, are there errors in the Apache logs?

Comment: Sorry, I should have checked the logs.
Doing so revealed the problem.

The error log tells me that the resources I wanted to access were group writable.

I removed write permissions from group and other.
I can now access the php pages from my browser.

My mistake was to make the permissions ultimately permissive, thinking that that would make testing easier.
(spot the noob)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What web server are you using? Has it been able to serve PHP files before?

if apache, make sure you have something similar to this in your config:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This is a new host that I've set up with hostgator.
As such, I can't directly edit the apache configuration. 
I understand that hostgator supports php. (The cpanel allows me to choose between versions of php)